# Match more than one occurrences in a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm using preg_match to find tag names in my template files.

Currently the closest one I've got is this:

`preg_match('/\{db:(.*)\}/',$haystack,$found);`

It works well for a string like this:

`<a href="index.php?view=products&cat={db:id}">Test</a>`

It returns me `id` just like I'm expecting. However, when using string with multiple occurrences like:

`<a href="index.php?view=products&cat={db:id}">{db:name}</a>`

it returns me `id}">{db:name`, not `id` and `name` as I'm expecting.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `(.*)` *non-greedy* by adding the `?` character, or it will take up as many characters as it can still match. Like this:

```
preg_match('/\{db:(.*?)\}/', $haystack, $found);
```

Comment: Yes and seems to that then I have to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`. Thank you!